# How to select count and max using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

in SQL I have the following statement that instances of errors in log files.  Can someone help me convert this into Linq?

```
select
    *
from
(
    select
        distinct
        bucket,
        count(bucket) as count, 
        max(error) as error
   from
        logs
   group by
        bucket
) a
order by
    count desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = logs
    .GroupBy(x=>x.bucket)
    .Select
    (x=>
        new
        {
            bucket = x.Key,
            count = x.Count(z=>z),
            error = x.Max(z=>z.error)
        }
    )
    .OrderByDescenting(x=>x.count);
```